# How to create a working makefile for a .cpp file

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to figure out how to get a makefile working for my .cpp file

Here is the code for main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello world!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my code for the make file:
    all: main.exe

```
main.exe: main.o
     g++ -o main.exe main.o

main.o: main.cpp
     g++ -c main.cpp
```

When I enter the command "make"

I get this: [image]

But when I run main.exe I get this:
[image]

And if I run main.exe as administrator I get this:
[image]

Comment: I am running this on Windows 64-bit though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile looks fine. However, it looks like you're compiling on a Linux machine through Putty. If that's true, there's your problem. Running g++ on Linux will target Linux. Simply appending .exe to your file name will not make it compatible with Windows.

There are tutorials out there for compiling for Windows on Linux, or you can install the proper compilers on your Windows machine, or simply run the compiled program inside a Linux environment.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Could I run the make file through cmd?

Comment: make isn't part of Windows without installing it. I've never actually done that, but it looks like [this link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) might be a good place to start. You'd probably need to install g++ or cl to compile code. I would imagine there are some other answers on this site about doing exactly that. However, if you're really just running something that small, it's probably easier just to execute it through Putty immediately after compiling.